# Is there a function(s) to copy a string into a new space in memory

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, free, calloc

If I want to copy the string `"Best School"` into a new space in memory in C programming, What statement(s) can I use to reserve enough space for it?

I have tried using this:

```
malloc(strlen("Best School") + 1)
```

And this also

```
malloc(sizeof("Best School"))
```

Comment: You need the `+1`, because `strlen` doesn't count the nul terminator at the end of the string.

Comment: `strdup` would be my go to solution

Comment: The `malloc` function allocates memory, it ***only*** allocates memory, nothing more. If you want to copy a string, use the `strcpy` function. Which should have been mentioned in any decent book, tutorial or course/class.

Comment: And while not a standard C function, POSIX (Linux and macOS) and Windows both have a `strdup` function which allocates *and* copies strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It will be a standard function from C23 though. Finally :-)

Comment: Also something that should have been mentioned by your learning or teaching resources, is that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. A string with four characters need a fifth special `'\0'` null-terminator character, to tell where the string ends. This is, as mentioned by @BoP, why you need +1 when allocating memory yourself.

Comment: Lastly about your question itself: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. As well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Your question seem to be about why you need +1 when allocating memory, not about the copying itself. Which makes your title misleading.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Finally indeed! :)

Comment: Just use `strdup(s)`, where `s` is the string to be copied.  This will call `malloc` to allocate space for the result string, then copy the original string into the result string, returning its address.

Comment: Both your versions are correct as far as the actual malloc goes, so the problem is elsewhere. You don't show the actual copying. Please post a complete example.

Comment: Maintenance headache. The literal string appears in `strlen()` and/or `sizeof()`... What's next? Repeating that literal string in the copy operation? What happens when one instance is changed, and by accident, the other isn't??

Comment: Given a literal string, simplest is to declare and initialize a new string `char s[] = "Best School";`

Comment: You ask a different question in the body of your post than you do in its title.  This has caused some confusion.  As far as "*What statement(s) can I use to reserve enough space for it?*", both alternatives presented in the question allocate a sufficient (and the same) amount of space, though that might not be true for original strings presented other than as string literals.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and safest way to allocate a block of memory and copy a null terminated string into it is:

```
    char *ptr = strdup("Best School");
```

`strdup()` is declared in `<string.h>`, has been part of the POSIX Standard since its inception and finally made it into Standard C as of C23.  It is available on most systems and can be defined this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strdup(const char *s) {
    size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *p = malloc(size);
    return p ? memcpy(p, s, size) : NULL;
}
```

Alternately, you could use `malloc`, `strlen` and `strcpy` directly:

`malloc` allocates a block memory of a given size. The memory is uninitialized, its contents are indeterminate, so if the allocation was successful, you must then copy the string into it, including the null terminator (`'\0'`). `"Best school"` is a null terminated string with 12 bytes: 11 characters plus a null terminator byte.

```
    // add 1 for the null terminator
    char *ptr = malloc(strlen("Best school") + 1);
    if (ptr) strcpy(ptr, "Best school");
```

And for string literals, you could even use `sizeof`:

```
    // sizeof includes the null terminator in a string literal
    char *ptr = malloc(sizeof "Best school");
    if (ptr) strcpy(ptr, "Best school");
```

But both of the above solutions are error prone because:

- one can easily forget to allocate or copy the extra byte for the null terminator. This bug causes undefined behavior, but can go undetected for some time because of the allocation granularity: e.g. allocating 11 bytes for `"Best school"` may return a block of 16 bytes and the 12th byte may happen to be a null byte, especially if this memory has not been used before.  This kind of undefined behavior is sly and will bite at the worst time.
- the `sizeof` version **only works for string literals!** If you want to allocate a copy of a string you only have a pointer to, `sizeof(ptr)` will evaluate to the size of the pointer, not that of the string, leading to undefined behavior for all but the shortest strings. This solution works for the example in the question, but should be disregarded.

The recommended solution is `strdup`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the memory and copy the original string. I would advice at the beginning (for educational purposes) to write all functions. Here is an example

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    char *end = str;
    if(str) while(*end) end++;
    return end - str;
}

void *mymemcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    if(dest && src)
    {
        const unsigned char *ucsrc = src;
        unsigned char *ucdest = dest;
        while(len--) *ucdest++ = *ucsrc++;
    }
    return dest;
}

char *mystrdup(const char *str)
{
    char *newstr = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    if(str)
    {
        len = mystrlen(str) + 1;
        newstr = malloc(len);
        if(newstr)
        {
            mymmemcpy(newstr, str, len);
        }
    }
    return newstr;
}
```

Comment: Good teaching! I would make 2 remarks: the standard functions do not have null pointer checks and more importantly you only copy `len` bytes instead of `len + 1` :)  Using `size_t size = mystrlen(str) + 1;` is much less error prone.

Comment: IMHO, the name `len` is misleading as the variable does not contain the *length* of the string returned by `mystrlen`.

Comment: @chqrlie length of the buffer not string

Comment: I understand that, but in the context it is somewhat misleading, as you experienced it yourself in the first post.